# Ruby on Rails Helper Method - HTML is displayed as plain text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a helper method for my Rails app that returns a string with HTML code for a Google Groups subscription form. Unfortunately, it comes out on the page like plain text. How can I force it to render as HTML?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us some code; particularly the spot in your ERB file where the helper is called and the results displayed.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The result of your helper needs to be marked as "html_safe" in Rails 3. Otherwise, the tags will be escaped.

```
def my_helper
  data = "<p>Hello!</p>"
  data.html_safe
end
```

Comment: I tried to accept the answer before, but it said I needed to wait 8 more minutes. Now it let me.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it was a problem with Rails html sanitize.
from rails changelog

> You no longer need to call h(string)
>   to escape HTML output, it is on by
>   default in all view templates.  If you
>   want the unescaped string, call
>   raw(string).

try it

Answer (score 2):

One thing to watch out for is when joining multiple strings like this

```
def custom_check_box(checked)
    '<span class="my-custom-checkbox '+( checked ? 'checked' : '')+'"></span>'.html_safe
end
```

In this case, only the last part is marked as html safe. Make sure you get the whole thing.

```
def custom_check_box(checked)
    ('<span class="my-custom-checkbox '+( checked ? 'checked' : '')+'"></span>').html_safe
end
```