# Create method in html.erb file

Tags: html, ruby, erb

I have to create one method in file say 'myCode.html.erb'. I have to write ruby code with html. So far I came to know how to write method and call that method as below.

```
method creation
<%def helo
    print "This is function"
end%>

<%=helo%> #calling method
```

But I'm in dilemma about how to write method in which I have to write both ruby and html code. Below is my code which I need to write in method.

```
<% 
   actions.each{ |action|
     tc = []
     bizA = []
     testcaseName = ''
     bizActionName = '' 
     @factory.testcases.rows({'steps.action._actionId' => action["_id"]}).each{|testcase|
       d = ''
       testcaseName = testcase['attributes']['name'] + d
       d = ', '
       tc << testcaseName
     }
    # require 'ruby-debug' ; debugger
     if !action['isGrouping']
     actions.each{|act|
     if act['isGrouping']
       temp = []
       temp = act['steps']
       temp.each{|step|
         if action['_id']==step['action']['_actionId']
           bizA << act['name']
         end
       }
      end 
     }
     end
%>
    <tr>
      <td><%= name %></td>
      <td><%= action['name']  %></td>
      <td><%= @factory.testcases.rows({'steps.action._actionId' => action["_id"]}).length %> </td>
      <td>
        <% counter=1%>
        <% for ix in 0..tc.length-1 %>
          <% if counter%2==0 %>
            <%if ix!=tc.length-1 %>
              <font color="black"><%= tc[ix] %></font> <br/>
            <%else%>
              <font color="black"><%= tc[ix] %></font> <br/>
            <%end%>
          <% else %>
            <%if ix!=tc.length-1 %>
              <font color="brown"><%= tc[ix] %></font> <br/>
            <%else%>
              <font color="brown"><%= tc[ix] %></font> <br/>
            <%end%>

          <%end%>
        <% counter=counter+1 end %>
      </td>
      <td><%=bizA.length%></td>
      <td>
        <% counter=1%>
        <% for ix in 0..bizA.length-1 %>
          <% if counter%2==0 %>
            <%if ix!=bizA.length-1 %>
              <font color="black"><%= bizA[ix] %></font> <br/>
            <%else%>
              <font color="black"><%= bizA[ix] %></font> <br/>
            <%end%>
          <% else %>
            <%if ix!=bizA.length-1 %>
              <font color="brown"><%= bizA[ix] %></font> <br/>
            <%else%>
              <font color="brown"><%= bizA[ix] %></font> <br/>
            <%end%>

          <%end%>
        <% counter=counter+1 end %>
      </td>  
    </tr>  
<% } %>
```

If I take the above created method `helo` as a reference and write this ruby+html code in that manner, it is not working. It is showing syntax error.

Comment: Please don't. Defining methods in views is very bad and shouldn't be practised. Define helper instead.

Comment: @MarekLipka... Appreciate your reply. I'm newbie in that manner. Can you be more specific or give me some example links so that it can be helpful.

Comment: You say "Showing syntax error."  But you don't show the syntax error.  I would guess it doesn't have much to do with the method or with HTML, but probably simply just syntax.  Something probably indicated in that error message you aren't showing.

Answer (score 2):

It is not likely what you really want to do.  But you can do it.

```
<% 
def hello
  'Hello World'
end
%>

<p>This is simply an erb file (really just a text file)</p>
<p><%= hello %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use helper method . Use rails DRY principle.

Just write Method in ApplicationHelper Module.

Example:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def halo
    "This is function" 
   end
 end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821435/ruby-on-rails-helper-method-html-is-displayed-as-plain-text

Answer (score 1):

Define method in some Helper

```
module TestHelper
  def test
    return 'Hello World'
  end
end
```

In your HTML file / .erb, you just insert

```
<%= TestHelper.test %>
```

In your HTML you will see 'Hello World'

Answer (score 1):

A correct way to do that is to define a partial that can consume parameters.

To achieve that, you render your partial from the calling view with:

```
<%= render partial: "my_partial", locals: {variable: "my value", other_variable: "other value"} %>
```

In the partial, you just render the value of the variables where you need them with:

```
<%= variable %>
```

For example,

```
<span>Variable has value <%= variable %>, while the other variable has value <%= other_variable %>.</span>
```