# How to reuse ERB templating code in function?

Tags: ruby, erb

I have this piece of code inside ERB template to render all articles in list.

```
    <% @list.each do |a| %>
    <article class="my-panel">
      <header>
        <h2><a href="<%= rel_url_to a[:rel_url] %>"><%= a[:name] %></a></h2>
         <time datetime="<%= to_datetime(a[:time]) %>"><%= time_description(a[:time]) %></time>
      </header>
       ... more stuff cut out
    </article>
    <% end %>
```

Now I am going to have to change it to something like this:

```
<% @list[content_splitter.before_ad_range].each  do |a| %>
   <%= render_article(a) %>
<% end %>

<%= AdCreator.between_content_ad %>

<% @list[content_splitter.after_ad_range].each do |a| %>
   <%= render_article(a) %>
<% end %>
```

I thought it would be nice to have `render_article` defined in template as opposed to having html clutter my ruby code. But when I move that code inside function I get an error.

This is the function:

```
  <% def render_article(a) %>
    <article class="my-panel">
      <header>
        <h2><a href="<%= rel_url_to a[:rel_url] %>"><%= a[:name] %></a></h2>
         <time datetime="<%= to_datetime(a[:time]) %>"><%= time_description(a[:time]) %></time>
      </header>

      <div class="image">
        <a href="<%= rel_url_to a[:rel_url] %>"><img alt="" src="<%= rel_url_to a[:img_url_1x] %>" srcset="<%= rel_url_to a[:img_url_2x] %> 2x, <%= rel_url_to a[:img_url_3x] %> 3x"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="text">
        <%= a[:article_text] %>
      </div>
    </article>
  <% end %>
```

This is the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `_erbout' for #<Html::FrontPage:0x0055fb94005c68>
```

Line of code producing this error is:

```
self.class.instance_variable_get(:@renderer).result(binding)
```

Why is this happening? How to find more informative error?

How to fix this? Can I avoid moving this obviously html dominant code into ruby helper file?

PS. I suspect problem is that functions `to_datetime` and `time_description` can't be accessed from inside ERB function.

I know that function `render_article` does get called because if I change it's signature to remove parameter I get an error

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
# (erb):45:in `render_article'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not technically impossible, but rather difficult and not recommended as can be seen by reading comments and answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839991/create-method-in-html-erb-filr).

As your error message points out your `def` won't quite happen in the context you "probably" expect and you certainly won't be able to "freely use `erb` features" while defining the method (since your context is completely different from what you expect).

The "railsy" way to do this is adding a helper or using a `partial`, but both come with their drawbacks. `.erb` files (as most templating-languages) do not "factor" well. If you want to factor things somewhat more freely you should look at the [`fortitude` gem](https://github.com/ageweke/fortitude) which provides what is basically a `ruby`-DSL for html which factors pretty easily. However, that is a rather drastic change from what you are probably used to.

If you *really* want to define a method inside an `.erb`-file then you would have to do it entirely within a single pair of `<% ... %>` brackets where you will have *only* access to your params, *not* your context. You would have to return what is basically a `String` in order to be able to use it in `<%= ... %>` and pay a hell of a lot of attention to escaping rules for everything to make it through. This is most probably more trouble than it is worth (but easy enough to do in `fortitude` :-).